# Find the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\vert f(a_{k+1})-f(a_k) \vert$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Define sequence $a_n=\cos(2n) \quad (n\geq1)$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}{\vert x \vert}$. Find the value of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\vert f(a_{k+1})-f(a_k) \vert$$

I don't know how to approach. I couldn't find any regulation of numerator (I mean the sum part.).

Comment: Your sum rewrites as $$\displaystyle \frac 2n \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\cos(2k)\cos(2k+2)<0}$$ and since $\displaystyle \cos(2k)\cos(2k+2) = \frac{\cos(2)+\cos(4k+2)}2$, $$\cos(2k)\cos(2k+2)<0 \iff d(4k+2,2\pi \mathbb Z) > \pi -2$$ so you're looking for the limiting proportion of integers such that $ d(4k+2,2\pi \mathbb Z) >  \pi -2$. But I don't know how to compute that by elementary means.

Comment: Could you include the answer below the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i) $\frac{1}{n}\sum_k\ |f(a_{k+1}-f(a_k)|$ is average of $
|f(a_{k+1}-f(a_k)|  $

ii) $\{\cos\ 2n |n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is distributed uniformly in
$[-1,1]$

iii) Assume that $ -\pi/2+M\pi <a_n<\pi/2+M\pi$ for some $M$. So the
probability of $ -\pi/2+M\pi <a_n<-\pi/2+M\pi+2$ is $\frac{2}{\pi}$
so that expectation of $ |f(a_n)-f(a_{n-1}) |$ is $\frac{4}{\pi}$.

Comment: I need some more details, I can't understand.